# saving own ggplot theme in package and document it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some custom changes on ggplot I do all the time, when I create graphs. I want to provide this theme in my package and I am not sure how to save and document it. It is no dataset nor a function. What is the preferred way of doing so?

```
my_theme <- theme_bw() + theme(plot.title=element_text(vjust=1))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point() + ggtitle('test') + my_theme
```

So I want to add `my_theme` to the documentation.

Comment: Try `my_theme()`? It is a function.

Comment: You can also use theme_set(my_theme) to use this theme within you whole session. You also do not need to define a function, `+ my_theme` does the trick too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just realised by looking at `theme_bw` that I can do it in the same way:

```
my_theme <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") {
  theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
    theme(plot.title=element_text(vjust=1))
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point() + ggtitle('test') + my_theme()
```

In this way I can just document my function...